# COUNT(*) is no echo in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my `var_dump` result in WordPress but when I want to echo `COUNT(*)` this showed error reports.
 **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*' in**

But `package` is showed well. **How can I echo each  `COUNT(*)`?**

**My sql is:**

```
$aaaaa = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT package, COUNT(*) FROM $table_name GROUP BY package");
```

**var_dump Result:**

```
 array (size=5)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[592]
          public 'package' => string 'package 1' (length=9)
          public 'COUNT(*)' => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[593]
          public 'package' => string 'package 3' (length=9)
          public 'COUNT(*)' => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[594]
          public 'package' => string 'Package 4' (length=9)
          public 'COUNT(*)' => string '2' (length=1)
```

**Echo:**

```
    echo  $aaaaa[2]->package;
    echo  $aaaaa[2]->COUNT(*);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your count column a simple text label:

`SELECT package, COUNT(*) as count FROM $table_name GROUP BY package`

Answer (score 1):

The name of the property is 'COUNT(*)', but it doesn't fit the standart rules of variables` naming. Nevertherless you still can use such names for the object's properties, but you can't access it by normal way. You can access it such way:

```
echo  $aaaaa[2]->{'COUNT(*)'};
```

But it would be better, if you give the label for count column field, as @morrisdj have proposed in the answer above.